# How to fit Google Earth satellite image to UK OS 50 DEM

Tags: dem, google-earth, digital-image-processing

I have extracted a DEM tile from the UK Ordnance Survey's free [OS Terrain 50 dataset](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html)
The tile contains spot heights for a grid comprising 51 nodes (West to East) by 51 nodes (North to South) with inter-node spacing 50m giving areal coverage of 2500m x 2500m.

I can load this DEM data into a home-made, browser-based, 3D viewer application (built with WebGL, THREE.js, javascript).

Now I wish to copy (for private use only) a satellite image from Google Earth (non-pro version) and apply it as a texture to the 3D viewer app.  I can do this in a rough and ready way by screen-snapping an image from Google Earth, then pasting the image into a paint program and then cropping and re-sizing.  I have done this manually in a rough way but getting accurate location and boundaries for the image will be laborious.  Also I expect that there may be horizontal positioning errors due to differences in the projections used by OS Grid and Google Earth.

I would like to know if there is a better way of extracting and processing the satellite image (using free software) to fit it to the DEM grid?

Comment: do you want the image in OSGB36 or do you want the DEM in WGS84 for Google Earth? - projecting the DEM (OS Terrain) to WGS84 might be a bit quicker.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the OS Grid as my base and transform the Google Earth image.